# Speed up while loop matching pattern in array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data array, with 2 million entries:

```
[20965  1239   296   231    -1    -1 20976  1239   299   314   147   337
   255   348    -1    -1 20978  1239   136   103   241   154    27   293
    -1    -1 20984  1239    39   161   180   184    -1    -1 20990  1239
   291    31   405    50   569   357    -1    -1 20997  1239   502    25
   176   215   360   281    -1    -1 21004  1239    -1    -1 21010  1239
   286   104   248   252    -1    -1 21017  1239   162    38   331   240
   368   363   321   412    -1    -1 21024  1239   428   323    -1    -1
 21030  1239    -1    -1 21037  1239   325    28   353   102   477   189
   366   251   143   452 ... ect
```

This array contains x,y coordinates of photons on a CCD chip, I want to go through the array and add up all these photon events in a matrix with dimensions equal to the CCD chip.

The formatting is as follows: `number number x0 y0 x1 y1 -1 -1`. The two `number` entries I don't care too much about, the x0 y0 ect. is what I want to get out. The `-1` entries is a delimiter indicating a new frame, after these there is always the 2 'number' entries again.

I have made this code, which does work:

```
i = 2
pixels = np.int32(data_height)*np.int32(data_width)
data = np.zeros(pixels).reshape(data_height, data_width)

while i < len(rdata):
    x = rdata[i]
    y = rdata[i+1]

    if x != -1 and y != -1:
        data[y,x] = data[y,x] + 1
        i = i + 2
    elif x == -1 and y == -1:
        i = i + 4
    else:
        print "something is wrong"
        print i
        print x
        print y
```

`rdata` is my orignal array. `data` is the resulting matrix which starts out with only zeroes. The while loop starts at the first `x` coord, at index 2 and then if it finds two consecutive `-1` entries it will skip four entries.

The script works fine, but it does take 7 seconds to run. How can I speed up this script? I am a beginner with python, and from *the hardest way to learn python* I know that while loops should be avoided, but rewriting to a for loop is even slower!

```
for i in range(2, len(rdata), 2):

    x = rdata[i]
    y = rdata[i+1]

    if x != -1 and y != -1:
        px = rdata[i-2]
        py = rdata[i-1]

        if px != -1 and py != -1:
            data[y,x] = data[y,x] + 1
```

Maybe someone can think of a faster method, something along the lines of `np.argwhere(rdata == -1)` and use this output to extract the locations of the `x` and `y` coordinates?

---

Update: Thanks for all answers!

I used askewchan's method to conserve frame information, however, as my data file is 300000 frames long I get a memory error when I try to generate a numpy array with dimensions (300000, 640, 480). I could get around this by making a generator object:

```
def bindata(splits, h, w, data):

    f0=0
    for i,f in enumerate(splits):
        flat_rdata = np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(data[f0:f].T)[::-1], (h, w))
        dataslice = np.zeros((w,h), dtype='h')
        dataslice = np.bincount(flat_rdata, minlength=pixels).reshape(h, w)
        f0 = f
        yield dataslice
```

I then make a tif from the array using a modified version of Gohlke's [tifffile.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html) to generate a tiff file from the data. It works fine, but I need to figure out a way to compress the data as the tiff file is >4gb (at this point the script crashes). I have very sparse arrays, 640*480 all zeros with some dozen ones per frame, the original data file is 4MB so some compression should be possible.

Comment: Do you need to keep track of the frame number?

Comment: At the moment not, but in the end I would like to make a tiff stack movie, then I will need the frame number.

Comment: OK, my answer preserves frame number now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like all you want is to do some boolean indexing magic to get rid of the invalid frame stuff, and then of course add the pixels up.

```
rdata = rdata.reshape(-1, 2)
mask = (rdata != -1).all(1)

# remove every x, y pair that is after a pair with a -1.
mask[1:][mask[:-1] == False] = False
# remove first x, y pair
mask[0] = False

rdata = rdata[mask]

# Now need to use bincount, [::-1], since you use data[y,x]:
flat_rdata = np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(rdata.T)[::-1], (data_height, data_width))

res = np.bincount(flat_rdata, minlength=data_height * data_width)
res = res.reshape(data_height, data_width)
```

Comment: Works, it now takes 0.2 seconds :). I did have to switch around data_height and data_width and transpose the final result to get what I want. I do have trouble understanding what ravel_multi_index exactly does, could you explain it?

Comment: Yeah, just noticed, added a [::-1], but however is fine. your rdata are x, y coordinates (or y, x). But np.bincount can only use flat integers, so it converts the x, y coordinates into the coordinates into a 1-d array of the same size.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to remove the `-1`s and `number`s:

```
rdata = np.array("20965  1239   296   231    -1    -1 20976  1239   299   314   147   337 255   348    -1    -1 20978  1239   136   103   241   154    27   293 -1    -1 20984  1239    39   161   180   184    -1    -1 20990  1239 291    31   405    50   569   357    -1    -1 20997  1239   502    25 176   215   360   281    -1    -1 21004  1239    -1    -1 21010  1239 286   104   248   252    -1    -1 21017  1239   162    38   331   240 368   363   321   412    -1    -1 21024  1239   428   323    -1    -1 21030  1239    -1    -1 21037  1239   325    28   353   102   477   189 366   251   143   452".split(), dtype=int)

rdata = rdata.reshape(-1,2)
splits = np.where(np.all(rdata==-1, axis=1))[0]
nonxy = np.hstack((splits,splits+1))
data = np.delete(rdata, nonxy, axis=0)[1:]
```

Now, using part of @seberg's method to convert the x-y lists into arrays, you can make a 3D array where each 'layer' is a frame:

```
nf = splits.size + 1            # number of frames
splits -= 1 + 2*np.arange(nf-1) # account for missing `-1`s and `number`s
datastack = np.zeros((nf,h,w))
f0 = 0                          # f0 = start of the frame
for i,f in enumerate(splits):   # f  = end of the frame
    flat_data = np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(data[f0:f].T)[::-1], (h, w))
    datastack[i] = np.bincount(flat_rdata, minlength=h*w).reshape(h, w)
    f0 = f
```

Now, `datastack[i]` is a 2D array showing the `i`th frame of your data.

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, could be dangerous to assume all the coordinates and "`numbers`" are positive.

Answer (score 0):

if `x0, y0, x1, y1 != -1` could you not do something like `filter(lambda a: a != -1, rdata)` and then not bother with the ifs? that could speed your code up.